# Duplicate already rendered Vue.JS component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, clone

I have the following Vue.JS component definition:

```
<table>
  <tr v-for="n in lines">
    <td>in stock</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td><button @click="lines++">+</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Which looks like like this:

[image]

And it allows the user to edit each cell and press the "+" button to add more rows. I want to duplicate the whole component, **all its content and functionality included** so that I can move it to a different part of the page and still be able to use the duplicated component and the original. Like this:

[image]

The problem is that clicking on the "+" button of the duplicated table (the one on the left) will no longer work because it is a mere HTML clone.

### **How can I "deep-copy" the whole component so that it remains usable?**

Note that the table can't be just wrapped into a `v-for` because the user is meant to clone more complex component structures like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcvYX.png).

Comment: Put the whole component in a `v-for`:   `<component v-for... `

Comment: @Dan The duplicated objects won't always be the same type and objects can be nested (see last paragraph), that is why I am looking for a way that does not use `v-for`.

Comment: Vue can be used in a data driven way - components are just layout for data - no cloning needed.